# Execução direta e por interpretação fazem o mesmo processo?

Tags: c, assembly, arquitetura-computadores, cpu

Eu estou lendo o livro *Organização Estruturada de Computadores*, de Tanenbaum, e em certo trecho ele diz:

> Após a especificação da linguagem de
> máquina, L, para um novo computador, a equipe de projeto pode decidir se quer construir um processador de hardware
> para executar programas em L diretamente ou se quer escrever um interpretador para interpretar programas em L. Se a
> equipe preferir escrever um interpretador, também deve providenciar alguma máquina de hardware para executá-lo. São
> possíveis ainda certas construções híbridas, com um pouco de execução em hardware, bem como alguma interpretação de
> software

Eu não entendi exatamente o que esse parágrafo quis dizer. Ele menciona que os projetistas podem decidir se vão projetar o processador de modo que possa executar instruções em *linguagem de máquina* diretamente ou então através de um software interpretador, mas qual exatamente seria a diferença? Os dois não vão executar a mesma linguagem de máquina? Ou o interpretador iria "mastigar" as instruções mais complexas em instruções mais simples e genéricas para que o processador possa executá-las mais fácil? Ou é só pra tornar o código mais portável entre diferentes arquiteturas? Talvez seja idiota mas eu estou realmente em dúvida sobre isso.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Você está confundindo especificação da linguagem com a implementação da linguagem.

Quando uma equipe de projeto de hardware decide uma linguagem de máquina (que o Tanenbaum chamou de L), isto é uma especificação. A primeira coisa que normalmente é feita é um interpretador dessa linguagem como uma primeira implementação dela. Esse interpretador, claro, vai ser construído, na maior parte das vezes, em uma linguagem C (ou mesmo linguagem de nível de abstração mais alto), em uma plataforma de hardware já existente.

Isso é feito para se verificar a linguagem em si, as possibilidades de implementação, as possíveis máquinas de estado da linguage e, principalmente, como desenvolver um compilador C para ela. Veja que, com este interpretador simples, já é possível a equipe de software partir para um compilador C (ou ajustar o clang ou gcc para isso).

Só depois que a linguagem em si vai ganhar uma implementação em hardware, isto é, um processador verdadeiro.

Hoje em dia é sim bem complexo o desenvolvimento de um hardware de computador.